# Product share on Facebook shows only one image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the standard Facebook code to share a product from my website. My problem is that only the first image is shared on Facebook.

The following code is used:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>';
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));
</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="page-url" data-layout="button"></div>
```

In the header I have added the multiple images (same property but different url):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url1"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="url2"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="url3"/>
...
```

How can I share multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

The meta og:image property only allows you to share one image with your facebook sharing link. There is no way to share multiple images with one button click. An alternative would be to concatenate the images of the products you want to share into a single image and use that as the og:image property.

You should also double check and make sure that the data-href has the correct value, otherwise you won't be sharing the link you want.

Comment: In the passed I used the old method with: <link rel="image_src" href="url1" /> and it worked with multiple images. But if I understand correctly, the old method is not working anymore and the new only supports one image?